# Matrix gradient differentiation calculation

Tags: vector-analysis, matrix-calculus, machine-learning

I came across this matrix calculus calculation:

> $$\begin{align} &\nabla_\mathbf{w} \left( \mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{X}^{\text{(train)}T} \mathbf{X}^{\text{(train)}}\mathbf{w} - 2\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{X}^{\text{(train)}T} \mathbf{y}^{\text{(train)}} + \mathbf{y}^{\text{(train)}T}\mathbf{y}^{\text{(train)}} \right) = 0 \\ &\Rightarrow 2\mathbf{X}^{\text{(train)}T} \mathbf{X}^{\text{(train)}} \mathbf{w} - 2\mathbf{X}^{\text{(train)}T} \mathbf{y}^{\text{(train)}} = 0 \end{align}$$

I'm having difficulty understanding how the authors performed the differentiation to $\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{X}^{\text{(train)}T}  \mathbf{X}^{\text{(train)}}\mathbf{w}$ of the first equation to get $2\mathbf{X}^{\text{(train)}T} \mathbf{X}^{\text{(train)}} \mathbf{w}$ of the second equation. In particular, I'm unsure of how to treat the transposed term $\mathbf{w}^T$. Can someone please explain this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be a symmetric matrix.

Let's consider the derivative of $w^TAw=\sum_{ij}w_iA_{ij}w_j$.

Differentiating with respect to $w_i$, we have $2\sum_{j}A_{ij}w_j$.

To see an example, suppose we want to differentiate with respect to $w_1$ where $n=2$

$$A_{11}w_1^2+A_{12}w_1w_2+A_{21}w_1w_2+A_{22}w_2^2$$

The partial derivative with respect to $w_1$ is

$$2A_{11}w_1 + A_{12}w_2+A_{21}w_2=2A_{11}w_1+(A_{12}+A_{21})w_2=2(A_{11}w_1+A_{12}w_2)$$

Similarly, the partial derivative with respect to $w_2$ is

$$ A_{12}w_1+A_{21}w_1+2A_{22}w_2=(A_{12}+A_{21})w_1+ 2A_{22}w_2=2(A_{21}w_1+A_{22}w_2)$$

That is we have $$\nabla_w(w^TAw)=2Aw$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So you came to the conclusion that, for $n = 2$, $\nabla_w (w^T Aw) = 2(A_{11}w_1 + A_{12}w_2) = 2Aw$? But what about $A_{22}$? It seems like that's missing, and you need the term with $A_{22}$ in order to get $2Aw$, no? Please clarify.

Comment: I was illustrating what happens when I differentiate with $w_1$, the term $A_{22}w_2^2$ will vanish when we differentiate with respect to $w_1$. Try to write down what happens when you differentiate with respect to $w_2$.

Comment: But then how is it correct to write that $\nabla_w(w^TAw)=2Aw$? After all, $A$ include $A_{22}$, right? Or am I misunderstanding the notation here?

Comment: I have added the derivative with respect to $w_2$ now. Now you can see that $A_{22}$ appearing.

Comment: Oh, I see now. So we have that $\nabla_w(w^TAw) = 2Aw = 2(A_{11} w_1 + A_{12}w_2) + 2(A_{21}w_1 + A_{22}w_2)$. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Nope, we do not add them up, the end result is a vector. The first entry is the partial derivative wrt to $w_1$, the second entry is the partial derivative with respect to $w_2$.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank you again. So the first entry of the vector would be $2(A_{11} w_1 + A_{12}w_2)$, and the second entry would be $2(A_{21}w_1 + A_{22}w_2)$?

Comment: yes, and we can compactly write them as $2Aw$.